# Pointer to a Structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a structure as shown. And I am able to initialise or modify any of its members normally when I have a pointer to the structure.

```
struct node{
    int key;
    int nno;
    char color;
    struct node* out;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* pre;
};
```

But, When I pass an address of the structure pointer to a function and capture the same using a double pointer, and trying to access the members using that double pointer, my compiler is throwing an error 'member undefined'.

```
void DFSVisit(struct node** u){
    *u->color = 'g';
    struct node* v;
    while(*u->out != NULL){
            v = *u->out;
                    if(v->color == 'w'){
                            v->pre = *u;
                            DFSVisit(&v);
                    }
    } 
    *u->color = 'b';
}
```

And, this is how I accessed the function.

```
DFSVisit(&root);
```

Root is a pointer properly initialized. And also, Root is a global variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you aware that the indirection (dereferencing) operator, `*`, has lesser precedence than the element selection operator, `->`? That is, you should be writing `(*u)->color`, not `*u->color`.

Answer (score 6):

`*u->color` parses as `*(u->color)` rather than your desired `(*u)->color` so the compiler complains because a `node*` has no `color` member (because it's a pointer rather than a struct!). So either explicitly insert the brackets like `(*u)->color` or introduce a local variable: `struct node *node = *u;` and use `node->color`